# How do I set server name to in "combobox" slot?

Tags: sql-server, server-name

I cant set my server name to default server name.

How can I set my server name to default server name in c# "add connection" part.
When I open first time "add connection", server name came with empty slot.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCbOw.png)
How do I add my server name to where I marked?

Comment: You should be able to just type the server name in to the box.